# stored procedure syntax in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, syntax

I am new to writing stored Procedures and I can't seem to find the error in this procedure.
The error is marked near the where part.

I tried looking for an example where the set is done based on a if condition but I can't seem to find such an example. Can anyone point me to my error?

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `incubation`.`bt_voice_modification` 
    (in input_slot varchar(45),in input_port varchar(45))
BEGIN
    SET @SVLAN_STH:=1000;
    SET @SVLAN_DTH:=999;
    SET @CVLAN_DTH:=1000;
    SET @FLOW_INSTANCE:=1;

    UPDATE one_2_one_table
        SET  L2S_USER_FLOW_INSTANCE = @FLOW_INSTANCE := @FLOW_INSTANCE+1;
        SET  L2S_NW_SLOT = input_slot;
        SET  L2S_NW_PORT = input_port;
        IF STH_DTH = 'STH' then
            set  L2S_NW_SVLAN = @SVLAN_STH :=@SVLAN_STH + 1;
        ELSE 
            set  L2S_NW_SVLAN = @SVLAN_DTH ;
            set  L2S_NW_CVLAN = @CVLAN_DTH :=@CVLAN_DTH + 1;
        END if;
        WHERE IPDSLAM_USER_SLOT = 2 AND L2S_USER_TYPE like "%gplt%";

END
```

Comment: Use the `CASE` clause, not `IF`. And commas between the `SET` clauses, not `;`. It would be good if you had an `ORDER BY`, too.

Comment: i tried adding the comma like this but the error is still the same. am i missing some thing?

IF STH_DTH = 'STH' then
            set  L2S_NW_SVLAN = /@SVLAN_STH :=@SVLAN_STH + 1;
        ELSE 
            set  L2S_NW_SVLAN = /@SVLAN_DTH ,
            set  L2S_NW_CVLAN = /@CVLAN_DTH :=@CVLAN_DTH + 1;
        END if;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code suggest you don't have a very clear picture of how `UPDATE` statement works or the exact syntax. When you put a `;`, it marks the end of the (UPDATE) statement. The syntax is - for one table:

```
UPDATE tableX

  SET columnA = what_value_should_columnA-get ,
      columnB = what_value_should_columnB_get ,
      ...
      columnX = what_value_should_columnX_get 

WHERE (conditions that restrict the rows that will be affected)

ORDER BY SomeColumn ;   --- this can be used in MySQL only. Standard SQL 
                        --- (and most DBMS) do not allow ORDER BY clause in
                        --- UPDATE statements. Since you are using variables
                        --- and the order of updating affects the updated values,
                        --- it's essential that you include an ordering.
```

So, your `UPDATE` would be something like:

```
UPDATE one_2_one_table
    SET  L2S_USER_FLOW_INSTANCE = @FLOW_INSTANCE := @FLOW_INSTANCE+1 ,
         L2S_NW_SLOT = input_slot,
         L2S_NW_PORT = input_port,
         L2S_NW_SVLAN = CASE WHEN STH_DTH = 'STH'
                               THEN @SVLAN_STH := @SVLAN_STH + 1
                               ELSE @SVLAN_DTH 
                        END ,
         L2S_NW_CVLAN = CASE WHEN STH_DTH = 'STH'
                               THEN L2S_NW_CVLAN
                               ELSE @CVLAN_DTH := @CVLAN_DTH + 1
                        END

WHERE IPDSLAM_USER_SLOT = 2 
  AND L2S_USER_TYPE like '%gplt%' 

ORDER BY SomeColumn ;
```

Comment: first of all thank you @ypercube. however the solotion does not work. what you said with the comas is marked as an error. i am using mysql perhaps what you wrought is valid for mssql?

Comment: when i use your code i get a syntax error near the second set.

Comment: again thank you!!!! @ypercube. no so that i will be clear when i need to set a condition on a set operation i cant do it in the way i tried i need to do it for each set independatly?